# gethostbyname() unknown error

Tags: c, sockets

I am trying to receive the IP address from a given domain. The domain is sent from a client to a local server and in the server I need to find the IP.

This is my code:

```
int hostname_to_ip(char * hostname, char* ip)
{
    struct hostent *he;
    struct in_addr **addr_list;
    int i;

    if ( (he = gethostbyname( hostname ) ) == NULL) 
    {
        herror("gethostbyname");
        return 1;
    }

    addr_list = (struct in_addr **) he->h_addr_list;

    for(i = 0; addr_list[i] != NULL; i++) 
    {
        strcpy(ip , inet_ntoa(*addr_list[i]) );
        return 0;
    }

    return 1;
}

int main() {
    int s;
    struct sockaddr_in server, client;
    int c, l, i;
    char buffer[100];
    char ip[100];
    struct hostent *ipAddress;
    struct in_addr **addr_list;

    s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    if (s < 0) {
        printf("Socket creation error!\n");
        return 1;
    }

    memset(&server, 0, sizeof(server));
    server.sin_port = htons(1234);
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

    if (bind(s, (struct sockaddr *) &server, sizeof(server)) < 0) {
        printf("Bind error!\n");
        return 1;
    }

    l = sizeof(client);
    memset(&client, 0, sizeof(client));

    for (i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
        recvfrom(s, &buffer, sizeof(buffer), MSG_WAITALL, (struct sockaddr *) &client, &l);
        printf("%s\n", "Client connected: ");
        printf("%s\n", buffer);
        char *host = buffer;
        hostname_to_ip(buffer, ip);
        printf("%s\n", ip);
    }

    close(s);
}
```

Message received is: unknown host and I cannot find why.

I am sure that i send a correct domain such as "www.google.com"

Comment: and that name does resolve on the test machine. plus, u are sure its not `http://www.google.com` - just checking

Comment: @pm100 checked and same result. It is very interesting because if I run only hostname_to_ip is working...

Comment: Did you know that `recvfrom` does not add a null terminator? Are you *sure* you're looking up `www.google.com` and not `www.google.comsdflehvyiu35tq35423xd34`?

Comment: @immibis I am printing the buffer after recvfrom and it returns www.google.com correctly.

Comment: stop in the debugger and verify byte for byte that you have the correct data in yr buffer

Comment: Make sure there are no spaces or newlines in `host`.

Comment: @Barmar and immibis both of you were wright! There was a new line. Fixed it and it is working! Thank you all for your patience!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this for loop is malformed:

```
for(i = 0; addr_list[i] != NULL; i++)  {
    strcpy(ip , inet_ntoa(*addr_list[i]) );
    return 0; 
}
```

It will bail out and return after the very first iteration.

I would start by fixing that.

Comment: The function is working if I take it separately and anyways it does not get there cause it breaks at if ( (he = gethostbyname( hostname ) ) == NULL)